# Autodesk Design Automation deployed to AWS

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Another question regarding design automation. 
I am trying to deploy the app to AWS but it seems that the appsettings.json file is not coming throug and the result is that I receive an error saying that the cliendid parameter is null.

Can someone help me through this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why appsettings.json didn't made it to your AWS but if you use Forge Design Automation SDK (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation), there is way how to setup ClientID and ClientSecret using environment variables.

```
Forge__ClientId=<your client id>
Forge__ClientSecret=<your client secret>
```